# Read Numbers Using OCR API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

A Live Codepen Demo [Here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWBBeLO?editors=1010) reads the horizontal numbers **( 12,32 )** on the picture since **OCR Terassect can only read horizontal text.** May I ask how to rotate the image by **90 degrees clockwise** so that the **number 98 is horizontal which we are able to read using Javascript**?  I know that you can just rotate the image orientation without javascript, but it is tedious. Are there any **other API that can read horizontal and vertical text** which are unlike Terassect that only reads **horizontal text**.?

`const worker = Tesseract.create();`

`const defaultImage = 'https://i.ibb.co/jLhP6d2/all-deides-num.jpg';`

Comment: What about using `elem.style.rotate = parseInt(elem.style.rotate,10)*1 + 90 + "deg"; `, where `elem` is your image element? You perform the rotation once the OCR for the original orientation is complete.

Comment: I think I saw [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273324/read-image-text-verticalhorizontal-using-ocr-tesseract) few hours ago. I hope you are not using StackOverflow to find someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, hi, I think I have tried the same method as you which I edited the html as  <img id="ocr__img" class="ocr__img" width="600px" style="transform:rotate(90deg);"/> , which rotates the image, but still, the OCR output reads the original image and not the rotated image. Are there other more convenient OCR Reader that reads vertical and horizontal text :) ? Thank you

Comment: @PawelKam, hello, this is not a homework, just some app I intend to do in my free time :), well, I have searched everywhere for an answer to this question but I found none, kind of upset :(

Comment: You might be able to use canvas to achieve a permanent rotation. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mawre723/). This would rotate the original image once, and change its `src` to a base64 representation of the image. You would then call the Tesseract's OCR function to read the permanently rotated image. I use the term *permanently* in the loosest possible sense - it's permanent as far as the DOM is concerned, but the image file itself won't be changed.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, hi,thank you for your reply, I have used your fiddle and added my picture https://jsfiddle.net/0rdwn5zo/1/, but when I try to open image in a new tab for the rotated picture, there are no options to get the image link for the rotated image ? :) My idea would be use the new rotated image link to be fed into my demo :)

Comment: You won't be able to get a URL, since the source is a base64 representation of the image. The rotation would have to be done in the same place you're using the Tesseract OCR. So, something like this: 1) In your Codepen, you would read the remotely loaded image (loaded via url) 2) Once that's done, rotate the image, like in the JS fiddle example 3) Once the rotation has been completed, call the Tessaract OCR again, to read the rotated image. All of this would be done in one place (one page), and all of your Javascript would need to be on that one page.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, ok sire, I will make the changes now :), sorry I am actually very new to programming but I try to learn :)

Comment: @FiddlingAway, hi, I have pasted your JS fiddle code into my codepen demo https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWBBeLO?editors=1010 , but it reads this "getcontext" error in the console :(

Comment: I've adapted your code a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/mawre723/1/ . Check the `/* new stuff */` markup to see what I've added and changed. Some notes: while it recognizes the 98  in the rotated image, it seems to be erroneously recognizing the upside down 36 as 95. Since it's most likely a limitation of the Tesseract library, I'm afraid I can't help more than that.